# How to extract a requesttoken from Response Header with regular expression in VS2017?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2017, access-token, web-performance

I want to fetch the Request token value from Response Header with regular expression and store it in param value so that can use it with other Requests.

RESPONSE HEADER:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Pragma : no-cache
Content-Encoding : gzip
Vary : Accept-Encoding
Cache-Control : no-cache, no-store
Content-Type : text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires : -1
Set-Cookie : ASP.NET_SessionId=c2xzcpszlmglyqgxrftmsnew; path=/; HttpOnly,__RequestVerificationToken=KWTEV0MoQcGxr_tZ2BwwvCvbD37Qu1fLbNyuVyJJJvKLCmGVeLS7qzpzP7woJgLbHNm9bRu3RlLE1kKxNj_s8C2LISNQViFZSYAfSWbr9Lo1; path=/; HttpOnly
Server : Webserver
X-UA-Compatible : IE=edge
```

I am using this in Regular Expression but it is not working

```
"Set-Cookie":"__RequestVerificationToken=(.*?)"
```

Comment: There are no double quotes in your example data. Try it like this `Set-Cookie :.*?__RequestVerificationToken=([^;]+)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/9XZKYu/2)

Comment: Not working. Same error > RegularExpression was not found in the response RegularExpression=Set-Cookie : .*?__RequestVerificationToken=([^;]+)

Comment: I would use @Thefourthbird's comment; with the note that unless the `Set-Cookie :.*?__` is somewhere else in the file, that bit is unnecessary. You can accomplish the same result just using `RequestVerificationToken=([^;]+)`

Comment: Or `(?<=__RequestVerificationToken=)\w+`

Comment: Or try `(?<=__RequestVerificationToken=)[^;]+`

Comment: None of the above worked in my case. I dont have code, I recorded the web performance test and now trying to parameterize it.

Comment: Sorry, but if `(?<=RequestVerificationToken=)[^;]+)` does not work, there is something else that prevents you from running the test. Check if `.UseRegularExpression = true` (if I am wrong about the property - what is the relevant documentation?).

Comment: https://www.bluey.com/2017/05/08/visual-studio-web-tests-oauth-taming-elusive-access-token/

Comment: I am using the above link. And as link suggested I am using regex with double quotes. But it is not working with or without quotes. 

Comment: (FYI: `(?<=RequestVerificationToken=)[^;]+` should have no `)` at the end)